# Disable IDE auto format command

Tags: eclipse, ide, formatter

I have a code base that many developers work on.  Some people blindly use auto format in their IDE and mess up the formatting of sql statements or other things.  It appears that some IDE's like eclipse do have the ability to use `//@Formatter:off` (which I have put around many things I do want to not get formatted), but by default these are ignored.  Thus, is there a way to either enable the setting so that will be used by default, or is there a way to disable any shortcut key linked to auto format using some sort of maven plugin?  Basically I am looking for a way to enforce this for anyone who is working on the codebase since everyone can change their own formatter settings.

I found https://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/format-mojo.html, but I dont think it can do either of those things.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Developers are using several different IDE's but primarily Eclipse